# Visio Interop Application events causing undesired behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, visio

I'm trying to use Visio Application events. When instantiating a new Application object, and setting any event (i.e. BeforeDocumentClose), this appears to result in unable to restore the Visio window after minimizing it.

I'm using VS/C# 2013, Windows Forms, Visio 2013 (on Windows 7). Though my main code project is huge implementing exchange between various office applications using Add-Ins, the following simple code reproduces the same issue. It is a Windows Forms project (with added Reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio).

```
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

Visio.Application app;
bool initialised = false;

private void visioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    init();

    app.Documents.Add("c:\\test.vst"); // creates new document from template
}

void init()
{
    if (!initialised)
    {
        // only initialise once
        app = new Visio.Application();
        app.BeforeDocumentClose += app_BeforeDocumentClose;
        initialised = true;
    }
}

void app_BeforeDocumentClose(Visio.Document doc)
{
}
```

Issue #1: This is the main issue. Creating one or more Visio Documents, the Visio Window is not maximized after being minimized. No Exceptions thrown as far as I can see. Windows just does it's audible error 'ping'.

Issue #2: This is a secondary issue. Creating two or more Visio Documents, hovering over the Windows Taskbar, the preview windows show the waiting cursor instead of normal document preview.

Conditions: Issue #1 only occurs when using an event on the Application. Document, Page/Shape events don't cause any problem. All events are captured fine. Issue #2 always occurs, but this is less important for me.

I've been searching for this issue for a while, but can't find anything related to it, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what is causing Visio to not respond to restore, but you can try the approach with "AddAdvise" instead:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class Form1 : Form, Visio.IVisEventProc
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Visio.Application app;
    bool initialised = false;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        init();

        app.Documents.Add("C:\\test.vst"); // creates new document from template
    }

    void init()
    {
        if (!initialised)
        {
            // only initialise once
            app = new Visio.Application();
            // app.BeforeDocumentClose += app_BeforeDocumentClose;
            app.EventList.AddAdvise(DocCloseEventCode, this, null, null);
            initialised = true;

            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }

    const short DocCloseEventCode = unchecked((short)Visio.VisEventCodes.visEvtDoc + (short)Visio.VisEventCodes.visEvtDel);

    object Visio.IVisEventProc.VisEventProc(short eventCode, object source, int eventID, int eventSeqNum, object subject,object moreInfo)
    {
        if (eventCode == DocCloseEventCode)
            app_BeforeDocumentClose(subject as Visio.Document);

        return null;
    }

    void app_BeforeDocumentClose(Visio.Document doc)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately this generates a COMException in:app.EventList.AddAdvise(DocCloseEventCode, this, null, null);

Comment: Did you copy the code from the post as-is? (take care about the the attributes [ComVisible(true)]. Means, to test, create a new winforms app with 1 button, and then copy-paste the code from the post.

Comment: Thank you again Nikolay, you were right. Adding the ComVisible attribute made this work. Marked as answer. I can't upvote as I haven't answered anyone's questions yet and can't comment until my rep is higher.

Comment: This indeed solves issue #1 (Visio becoming unresponsive after minimizing).  I'm not sure this solution will work for my complete application but that's something I will explore now. An additional query, do you know if there is an AddAdvise event for Visio (application) closing entirely?

Comment: There is a table (map) of event to codes.. close = app.BeforeQuit = (visEvtApp+visEvtBeforeQuit). Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768620.aspx

Comment: That's brilliant, just what I needed. As mentioned I'll try this solution on my full application which is significantly more complex than my example, so will need to sort out where best to catch events (hoping this can be distributed in a suitable way). It will be worth the effort if improving Visio stability/functionality avoiding my main issue. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

To provide the completed solution for multiple events using Nikolay's advice, here is the completed code including both events and (de)initialisation of Visio Application, and without using templates. (Note that the Message boxes may turn up in the background, behind the Visio window.)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

namespace VisioInteropTest
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public partial class TestForm : Form, Visio.IVisEventProc
    {
        Visio.Application app;
        bool initialised = false;

        // all AddAdvise events:
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768620.aspx
        const short appCloseEventCode = (short)(Visio.VisEventCodes.visEvtApp | Visio.VisEventCodes.visEvtBeforeQuit);
        const short docCloseEventCode = (short)(Visio.VisEventCodes.visEvtDoc | Visio.VisEventCodes.visEvtDel);

        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void visioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (init())
            {
                app.Documents.Add("");
            }
        }

        bool init()
        {
            if (!initialised)
            {
                app = new Visio.Application();
                app.EventList.AddAdvise(appCloseEventCode, this, null, null);
                app.EventList.AddAdvise(docCloseEventCode, this, null, null);
                initialised = true;
            }
            return initialised;
        }

        object Visio.IVisEventProc.VisEventProc(short eventCode, object source, int eventID, int eventSeqNum, object subject, object moreInfo)
        {
            switch (eventCode)
            {
                case appCloseEventCode: app_BeforeAppClose((Visio.Application)subject); break;
                case docCloseEventCode: app_BeforeDocumentClose((Visio.Document)subject); break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        void app_BeforeAppClose(Visio.Application app)
        {
            initialised = false;
            MessageBox.Show("App closed");
        }

        void app_BeforeDocumentClose(Visio.Document doc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Doc closed");
        }

    }
}
```